# backbone: How to get a particular row from the collection by username rather than id?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-1.9

How can I get a particular row from the `backbone.collection` by `username` rather than `id`?

I think the most common case,

```
site.come/#edit_contact/5
```

But I need to get the item from the collection by username/ email or code,

```
site.come/#edit_contact/user1
site.come/#edit_contact/lau@xxx.com
site.come/#edit_contact/T1X0A7
```

backbone by id,

```
model = AB.contactscollection.get(id);
```

ideally,

```
model = AB.contactscollection.get(username);
```

Is it possible?

**Note:**

I am using the code from this tutorial for testing,

http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/writing-your-first-application-using-backbone-js/

**EDIT:**

```
    var contact = {},

    //model = AB.contactscollection.get(id);
    model = AB.contactscollection.where({email: "lau@xxxx.com"})
    if (id !== undefined && model !== undefined) {

        contact = model.toJSON();
    }
    this.$el.html(this.template({contact: contact}));
```

error message,

> TypeError: model.toJSON is not a function
>
> contact = model.toJSON();

Comment: Do you want to fetch a special model from the server based on the username or do you want to get the model from the local collection you already fetched, based on the username?

Comment: Yes, I want to  `get the model from the local collection you already fetched, based on the username` - is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a model from a collection based on a model attribute you can use where:

```
collection.where({username: "user1"});
```

See documentation here: [Collection where](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where)

Edit:

If you always select your models based on the username or email attribute you can make it the [idAttribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute), and then use the username as your id if it is unique:

In the model:

```
idAttribute: "username"
```

and then get the model from the collection based on this:

```
collection.get("user1");
```

EDIT2:

Look for [findWhere](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere) in the docs if you want to return only one model (the first one found) from your collection, you should be sure that the attribute you are searching for is unique:

```
collection.findWhere({username: "user1"});
```

Comment: thanks a lot!. What about if it is the scenario that I need `to fetch a special model from the server based on the username`?

Comment: you could implement it like a search site.come/#edit_contact/?username=name1 and in backbone collection.fetch({data:{username:"name1"}});

Comment: Now I have the further problem after using `.where` any idea why? please see my edit above. thanks!

Comment: @lauthiamkok Return value of `where` is `Array`, something like this : `[Model]`, if you want to get single element (and that attribute is uniq) you can use `collection.find`.

Comment: how can I use `find` - can't find it in the backbone's doc. thanks.

Comment: i get an error for using `findWhere` though, `TypeError: AB.contactscollection.findWhere is not a function`

Comment: are you using backbone version below 1.0.0? findWhere was introduced with 1.0.0